# Unable to apply parameterised curried function

Tags: scala, currying

I have a function, that has the following definition:

```
def expectMsgPF[T](max: Duration = Duration.Undefined, hint: String = "")(f: PartialFunction[Any, T]): T = {
```

When I call it as follows:

```
val res1 = listener1.expectMsgPF(1.second)
```

Is `res1` a function?

I would like to write as follow:

```
 val res1 = listener1.expectMsgPF(1.second) _
 val res2 = listener2.expectMsgPF(1.second)
 Then("it should contain `Kafka and SAP are offline`")
 res1 {
    case status: ServerStatus =>
    status.health should be(ServersOffline)
  }
```

But it does not work.

Comment: `expectMsgPF` is a method, not a function. - `res1` can be a function, if the expected type is of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `res1 { case status: ServerStatus => status.health should be(ServersOffline) }` work, try helping the compiler out by providing type parameter `T` to `expectMsgPF[T]` like so

```
val res1 = listener1.expectMsgPF[Assertion](1.second) _
```

This makes `res1` indeed a function of the type

```
PartialFunction[Any, Assertion] => Assertion
```